# Where has "Show Type Info on Mouse Motion" gone in Intellij 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

According to the following link I can enable this option:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Show+Type+Info+Action

But I have just installed IntelliJ 14.1 and there is no "IDE Settings" when I open the "Settings" dialog. Can someone tell me how to set this option in this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Scala settings have changed and most documentation is outdated.

I think the setting you are looking for is located here:

<kbd>File</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Settings</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Languages & Frameworks</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Scala</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Editor Tab</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Show type info on mouse hover after, ms</kbd>